# Sort a Dataframe using External Factor Ordering in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

A niggling problem. Simple example. Suppose I have the following:

```
df <- data.frame(x = as.factor(1:10),
                 y = rnorm(10, 0, 1))

x_order = c("3", "1", "5", "7", "8", "9", "2", "6", "10", "4")
```

I would like to reorder the rows of `df` such that the values in `df$x` appear in the order specified in the `x_order` vector. Is there an easy way to do this please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert the 'x_order' to `integer` and use as row index

```
df1 <- df[as.integer(x_order),]
```

---

In a general case, we can use `match`

```
df1 <- df[match(x_order, df$x),]
```

Or convert the 'x' column to `factor` with `levels` specified as 'x_order`and do`order`

```
df[order(factor(df$x, levels = x_order)),]
```

Comment: Would this still work if x was categorical  (eg 10 names, 10 star signs, etc.)?

Comment: @Alan If it is `x_order <- c('A', '&', 'a', 'hello', '**', '*', '>>', '88', 'x', 'no')` what would  be the order and how do we determine the order

Comment: @Alan Perhaps `match` wouldd be what you are looking for

Comment: Ahhh I see your general case comment above. Thank you. I'll see if I can apply the method to my more complex real data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R solution, where you can use `rownames` of `df` to re-order the rows of `df`, i.e.,

```
dfout <- df[match(x_order,rownames(df)),]
```

such that

```
> dfout
    x           y
3   3  0.08897425
1   1  0.96173905
5   5  0.81658185
7   7  0.19946419
8   8 -0.21296035
9   9  0.16236732
2   2 -0.32710972
6   6  0.11647613
10 10  0.26953532
4   4  1.17435024
```

Comment: @akrun well, yes, I assumed it from the special case given from example